# How Redis Sentinel work with Bull queue (using NestJS)

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs, bull-queue

I am working on a NestJs project using Bull queue.
Here is the code I am using to connect Redis, and it works well。

```
BullModule.registerQueueAsync(
      {
        name: 'test',
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          redis: {
            host: configService.get('REDIS_ADDR'),
            port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
          },
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService],
      }
)
```

Now, I need to switch to using Redis Sentinel.
I searched online, but I could not find an appropriate tutorial.

I appreciate any help you can provide.